# I need to find duplicates from two different columns in an excel but it should ignore duplicates in same column

Tags: excel

I have data in two different columns ColA and ColB in Excel. I want to highlight ColA if there is a duplicate found in ColB and I want to avoid highlighting if duplicate record is found in same column which is ColA. I am using Conditional Formatting - Highlight cell rules -  Duplicate Values.

Comment: The *"if there is a duplicate found in ColB"* is unclear. Depending on what that means, try either `=AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$13,A2)>1,COUNTIF(B$2:B$7,A2)>1)` or `=AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$13,A2)>1,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B$2:B$7,0)))`. Maybe replace the first two conditions with `COUNTIF(A$2:A$13,A2)=1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a formula for your conditional formatting.

eg:

If this is what you expect:
[image]

then the conditional format formula would be:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,$B$1:$B$6,0))
```

[image]